# Is sign output of the node.js/crypto module portable?

Tags: node.js, cryptography

I'm trying to create a digital signature using the `crypto.sign` API of the node.js `crypto` module. I've confirmed that I can verify the signature by giving its output buffer to `crypto.verify`, but is it possible to verify this output with other software (e.g. signature libraries for other languages)?

settings:

- Node.js version: v14
- Signature algorithm (key) used: ed25519

```
const keyPair = await generateKeyPair('ed25519');
const signature = crypto.sign(null, Buffer.from('data'), keyPair.privateKey);
```

- Public key exchange format: PEM
- Signature data exchange format : Base64 encoding of crypto.sign output buffer <del>(should be PKI's CMS or JWS standard format, but...)</del>

What I'm wondering:

- How should I handle the byte order when verifying base64 back to byte string in various languages?
- What other things should I be aware of?

Comment: The signature from nodejs `crypto.sign` (really OpenSSL `EVP_Sign{Init,Update,Fini}`) is not CMS or JWS, nor TLS SSH PGP XMLdsig PKIX/X.509 or any other generic/multi-algorithm scheme. It is algorithm-specific; for RSA it is PKCS1=RFC8017, for DSA 3279, for ECDSA 3279 5480 SEC1 and purportedly X9.62, and **for EdDSA (your case) RFC8032. It should be interoperable** with anything else that implements 8032 including CMS with 8419 and JWS/JWA with 8037, and PKIX with 8410, if key(s) and data are correct of course. 8032 standardizes byte (and bit) order for you.

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry for the confusion.  I mean that "I'd like to use some kind of standard signature format, but I used a raw output from the sign algorithm." in the deleted sentence. I don't think crypto module's sign api returns CMS or JWS. Anyway, I'll check RFC8032.